Special Steiner Tree problem (parsimony problem) when the tree topology is known
Given a tree T with leaf nodes $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}$, internal nodes $\{Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_m\}$, and edge set $E(T)$, each leaf node is associated a given point $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$. The goal is to find points $y_1,y_2,...,y_m\in \mathbb{R}^d$, corresponding to each $Y_i$, that minimize the total cost $$\sum_{(W,Z)\in E(T)}d_{euc}(w,z)$$. Here $d_{euc}$ is the Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $w,z$ are associated points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ corresponding to the nodes $W$ and $Z$.
This is a small parsimony problem with cost function to be the euclidean distance, and it is also a special case of the Steiner tree problem when the tree topology $T$ is known, so that we just need to place the coordinates of these internal nodes. Besides, the degrees of some nodes in T could be larger than 3.
I am wondering if there is any previous work discussing the hardness of this problem and approximation algorithms on solving that.
Thanks!
